# Closed subset of an open subset of Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

My question is kind of silly because it's so simple, but I'm very careful about my proofs and don't want to make errors.

Specifically, I'm looking at Prop. 5.5 of Lee's *Smooth Manifolds* (my go to reference) in the context of Euclidean space and my question is the following: Let $Q$ be the subset of $R^{n-1}$ consisting of vectors with strictly positive components and $R$ be the strictly positive reals. Then we take in the proposition $M \equiv Q \times R$ (the positive orthant of $R^n$) and $S$ to be the graph of some smooth (say, $C^1$) strictly positive function $f$ on $Q$. We know from Prop. 5.4 that $S$ is an embedded submanifold of $M$ of codimension one. My question: Is $S$ closed as a subset of $M$, as the proposition requires?

My take is yes, using the definition of "closed as a subset of $M$" the following: If $x \in M$ is a limit point of a sequence contained in $S$ then $x$ must be in $S$. My view of this (roughly speaking) is that the only limit points of sequences in $S$ that are not in $S$ live in the hyperplanes $x_i = 0, 1 \leq i \leq n-1$, and those are not in $M$. Of course $S$ would not be closed *as a subset of* $R^n$, but that is not the requirement.

Am I off here? Any suggestions as to why I'm correct, or incorrect, would be appreciated.

**Edit**: @Dan Rust suggested looking at the fact that $M \setminus S$ is open. I also realized an equivalent way of dealing with this is to argue that $Q$ is closed as a subset of itself so that, since $f: Q \rightarrow M$ is assumed smooth, $S = f(Q)$ must be closed in $M$. I just want to be careful about the topologies.

Comment: In this case, it's easier to think of the complement. For $S$ to be closed, you want its complement in $M$ to be open, which, in this case, it is.

Comment: Appreciate the comment, yes, I'll think about what your approach does to sidestep the difficulty I was having (I'm sure it does, just have to convince myself). I modified the question to include both your observation and one more that just came to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\langle x,y\rangle\in Cl_M(S)$ then there is a sequence $(\langle x_j,f(x_j)\rangle)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ of members of $S$ converging to $\langle x,y\rangle.$ This requires that $(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$  converges to $x$ and

$(f(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $y.$

Now $\langle x,y\rangle\in Cl_M(S)\subset M=Q\times R$ so $x\in Q.$ The continuity of $f$ on $Q$ implies that if a sequence $(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ in $Q$ converges to $x\in Q$ then

$(f(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ converges to $f(x).$

So  $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,f(x)\rangle\in S.$

Comment: Yes, this is clear, my only issue was if it was correct to "ignore" the points in the hyperplanes bounding P because they are not in M. I know it sounds silly but, again, I just wanted to bounce this off someone else. My real issue is when f is only defined on some open subset U of Q, so boundary points of U do have to be taken into consideration. I believe I've got that handled as well; regardless I've marked your answer correct and thank you (and @Dan Rust) for responding.

Comment: When asking whether a subset of M is closed in the subspace M, we can ignore any points not in M.